# How can I write a bash command that takes 15 mins to run before another command is executed in Ansible?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I am trying to update the version of some software through Ansible for a server.

```
    - name: upgrade firmware version
      shell: bash -x bmc_firmware_update.sh -k -F BMC_0204.00.bin_enc -s 1
```

this could take about 15 mins to run. I have another command to run after that, i.e

```
    -name: something else
     shell: bash -x bmc_firmware_update.sh -k -F BMC_0204.00.bin_enc -s 2.
```

I came across wait_for: timeout=300 but I want to know if there is a better way to go about making sure that the first one is successfully completed before the second shell command is run. Please advice!

Comment: A *compound command* would ensure that the first completes before the second starts, e.g. `command1 && command2` will only run `command2` after the *successful* completion of `command`.

Comment: The bash script took care of this for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has nothing to do with Ansible.

Programs runs in foreground by default.

Answer (score 0):

@sorin this is Ansible related!

@op; You can append to the `firmware_update.sh` script that when finished, it writes a certain value to specific path. Then let Ansible check that file and if that value is there. If it is, continue, if not, retry.

Another possibility is to write the logic in the bash scripts themselves.